# Unirational algebraic group scheme smooth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, group-schemes

Let $G$ an *unirational* algebraic $k$-group over base field $k$ in sense of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-51438-8) on Neron models, (ie separated $k$-group scheme of finite type).

On page 310 is claimed that unirationality implies that $G$ is smooth.

**Question:** Why this is the case? Firstly wlog we can assume that $G$ is even affine, since as a group scheme it suffice to show that it is smooth in an open dense subscheme due to transitivity of self-action.

**[#UPDATE NO 1: Forget this paragraph, assume $k$ perfect, eg after passing to alg closure; The really cruicial problem is why $G$ is reduced]** The crucial problem I see here is that we nothing assume about base field $k$. Eg if $k$ would be perfect, then there is a nice characterization that geometrically reduced group schemes are smooth and unirationality assures that the affine ring $A_G$ of $G$ is mapped to $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, such that the kernel of this map is the radical due to dominance. Is it zero in this situation?
But I not see how to argue in the case $k$ arbitrary.

#REASON for Update above: I noticed only few days after posting this question that the authors defined an algebraic $k$-group to be only $k$-group scheme of finite type, that's it.
*Especially no assumption on geometric reducedness* as I wrongly initially assumed as prepared this question, so suggested reasonings above to show smoothness via geometric reducedness (see eg [tag/0BF6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BF6)) don't work immediately so far I see (...at least not in direct way I intended to use it; instead showing reducedness becomes the main problem) and led to the wrong track, sorry for causing this confusion.

So forget about issues on base field $k$, let pass to it's algebraic closure ( ie can wlog assume $k$ is perfect) and unirationality says that we have a rational dominant mapping $\mathbb{A}^n \to G$.
Nevertheless, why the claim above about smoothness for this unirational algebraic $k$-group should be still true?

**#UPDATE NO 2:** As @Matthieu Romagny in the comments explained the authors assumed for treatise of the notion of unirationality that the involved $k$-scheme is already a $k$-variety, especially geometrically reduced.

Well, in that case applying this assumption to out algebraic $k$-group $G$, the "*uniraationality*" seems itself to be a red herring regding smoothness issues due to [/tag/047P](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/047P), isn't it? (compare also with @JasonStarr's and @Remy van Dobben de Bruyn's comments)

That is we only need to assume $G$ geom reduced, the unirationality itself seems to superfluous condition, isn't it?

But then this evolves the original question to following natural subsequent question:
**Question':** Assume $G$ is an affine $k$-group scheme of finite type ($k$ perfect; eg after passing to alg closure) - eg we not assume a priori $G$ geom reduced! - and assume there exist a *dominant rational map* $\mathbb{A}^n \to G$. (ie "unirationality" with dropped $k$-variety assumption)

Does there exist a non smooth example satisfying these assumptions?

Comment: Every geometrically reduced, locally finite type group scheme is smooth.  Use generic smoothness and the fact that the singular locus is stable under automorphisms.

Comment: The properties "geometrically reduced" and "smooth" (= "geometrically regular") can all be tested over $\bar k$, so it does not matter whether $k$ is perfect, algebraically closed, etcetera.

Comment: I think there still a gap I not noticed before since when posting this question I wrongly assumed that the authors assumed an algebraic $k$-group to be geometrically reduced, but that's not the case; in the linked book an algebraic group is defined to be just a $k$-group scheme of finite type, so to show smoothness via geometr reducedness seemingly not work directly here. Nevertheless why such $G$ is smooth assuming it is unirational?

Comment: The definition of unirationality for $G$ is that, apart from the properties you mention, the field of rational functions of $G$ is purely transcendental over the base field.

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: could you give a reference where you found this definition of *unirationality*? This sounds more like *rationality*, because unirationally demands only existence of rational dominant mapping $\mathbb{A}^n \to G$, therefore the condition on field of rational fct's of $G$ - call it $K(G)$ - should be read as that it is "contained" in a purely transcendental field - namely $K(\mathbb{A}^n)$ - but $K(G)$ itself is not required to purely transcendental; see Def on the same page 310 in the linked book. Or do I misunderstand your concern?

Comment: @user267839 The definition is from the book you mention (Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud), except that -- you're right -- I wrote the definition of rationality. For unirationality the condition is "... contained in a purely transcendental field extension of the base field".

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: yes that's the issue! For rational $G$ the story is quite easy: we have birationality, so iso between $ \mathbb{A}^n $ and $G$ over appropriate open subschemes, especially therefore there exist a closed $g \in G$ whose stalk is regular, and then we use transitivity of selfaction by multipl of $G$. So $G$ smooth (= regular, if we passed before to alg closure) But the story for unirational $G$ seems to more complicated...

Comment: @user267839 I think that you misunderstand what the authors of Néron Models write. They write clearly that a $K$-variety is geometrically reduced. In the sentence after they speak about an algebraic $K$-group, the underlying scheme of which is an algebraic $K$-variety. Indeed they say that it is unirational if its underlying scheme is unirational, which can only refer to the definition before.

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: I see the issue now, but isn't then - assuming this that $G$ is already $K$-variety, so geom reduced - the assumption that $G$ unirational a red herring
regarding smoothness issues? 
(see [tag/047N](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/047N); ie only the geom reducedness matters, the assumption that $G$
unirational itself can be left out?)

Comment: Going away from varieties, one could ask following question: Assume $G$ is $k$-group scheme of finite type ($k$ perfect) and there exist a dominant rational map $\mathbb{A}^n \to G$ (...so we mimic the unirationality condition, but drop the $K$-variety assumtion). Is there a conterexample known for such $k$-group scheme of finite type, which satisfies this property above, but isn't smooth?

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: #EDIT Above I gave wrong link; I meant [/tag/047P](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/047P), sorry!

Comment: @user267839 I believe that this can't happen, because if $f:\mathbb{A}^n\to G$ is dominant then $G$ is reduced, hence integral. Then by generic flatness $f$ is flat over some open $U\subset G$, hence remains flat after passage to an algebraic closure. Hence $f_{\bar{k}}$ is flat and this implies that $G_{\bar k}$ is reduced, hence $G$ is in fact smooth.

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: That's the problem. If we only assume $G$ $k$-group scheme of finite type (wlog $G$ affine) and we have a dominant $f:\mathbb{A}^n\to G$, why $G$ reduced? On level of rings dominance traslates to that the kernel of ring map $A[G] \to k[x_1,..., x_n]$ is contained in the radical ideal $\sqrt{(0)}$, and because it is prime, it is the complete radical. But why should it be zero? (what is equivalent to reducedness of $G$)

Comment: @user267839 Ah but dominant should be understood schematically, that is, the map $k[G]\to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ should be assumed *injective*. Without this condition the question hardly makes any sense: if you take any infinitesimal, non trivial (hence nonreduced) group scheme $H$ then $G:=\mathbb{G}_a\times H$ will have a topologically dominant (in fact homeomorphic) map $\mathbb{A}^1\to G$...

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny: That's where the dog is buried, thank you for the explanations! I interpreted the dominance the whole time topologically, that's what caused the cascade of confusions...